# Label outliers in Pandas df using IQR

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to identify outliers that are **below the 25th percentile or above 75th percentile** for overall daily_visitors split by store_id and **label them with in a new column for 1 == outlier and 0 == no outlier**

Main DF

```
date         store_id     store_category   daily_visitors
2020-01-01   1            small            190
2020-01-02   1            small            187
2020-01-03   1            small            145
2020-01-04   1            small            156
2020-01-05   1            small            134343
2020-01-01   2            large            4635
2020-01-02   2            large            4321
2020-01-03   2            large            4534
2020-01-04   2            large            4242
2020-01-05   2            large            21
```

Output DF

```
date         store_id     store_category   daily_visitors  outlier 
2020-01-01   1            small            190             0
2020-01-02   1            small            187             0
2020-01-03   1            small            145             0
2020-01-04   1            small            156             0
2020-01-05   1            small            134343          1
2020-01-01   2            large            4635            0
2020-01-02   2            large            4321            0
2020-01-03   2            large            21              1
2020-01-04   2            large            4242            0
2020-01-05   2            large            21              0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.select`:

```
In [2272]: conditions = [df.daily_visitors > df.groupby('store_id')['daily_visitors'].transform('quantile', 0.75), df.daily_visitors < df.groupby('store_id')['daily_visitors'].transform('quantile', 0.25)]

In [2273]: choices = [1,1]

In [2276]: df['outlier'] = np.select(conditions, choices)

In [2277]: df
Out[2277]: 
         date  store_id store_category  daily_visitors  outlier
0  2020-01-01         1          small             190        0
1  2020-01-02         1          small             187        0
2  2020-01-03         1          small             145        1
3  2020-01-04         1          small             156        0
4  2020-01-05         1          small          134343        1
5  2020-01-01         2          large            4635        1
6  2020-01-02         2          large            4321        0
7  2020-01-03         2          large            4534        0
8  2020-01-04         2          large            4242        0
9  2020-01-05         2          large              21        1
```